# Scikit learn ngram_range purpose in TF-IDF vectorizer?

Tags: scikit-learn

What is the use of ngram_range in vectorizers like countvectorizer and TF-IDF vectorizer. I mean ngram_range(1,1) is for unigram. what it means for ngram_range(1,2) and (2,2)???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ngram_range(1, 2) means unigrams and bigrams, (2, 2) means only bigrams..
Don't you think the [docstring](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) is precise enough:

The lower and upper boundary of the range of n-values for different n-grams to be extracted. All values of n such that min_n <= n <= max_n will be used.

How would you change the docstring to be more helpful?

Comment: A very late comment but Andreas' first sentence here gives a perfect example that could help someone new to learn quickly, therefore if such an example is added to the docstring, it would render a newbie's life a little better. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer really helped me understand the conceptof ngram_range(); https://www.quora.com/How-are-TF-IDF-vectorizers-with-n-gram-features-created this answer really fleshed out all the details for me; kudos!